# What happens if we let time expand in the FLRW metric?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, time, space-expansion

If we multiplied the time differential (dt) by a scale factor that depends on time in the FLRW metric, what would this imply on cosmology? In particular, what are its implications on the cosmological principle?

Comment: Assuming a flat space, the FLRW metric is $ds^2=dt^2-a^2(t)(dr^2+r^2 d\Omega^2)$. Is your question "what happens when we have $a(t) \leadsto a(f(t))$ for some function $f$?" If so, rename $a \circ f$ into just $a'$. Maybe you have a particular example of the FRLW metric in mind...

Comment: No, I mean what happens if the dt was multiplied by a scale factor that either expands or contracts with time.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 2):

If you have the metric,
\begin{equation}
ds^2=b^2(t) dt^2-a^2(t) d\vec{x}^2
\end{equation}
You can make a coordinate transformation,
\begin{equation}
\tau=\int b(t) dt
\end{equation}

Then you can rewrite the metric in the usual FLRW form
\begin{equation}
ds^2=d\tau^2-a^2(t(\tau)) d\vec{x}^2
\end{equation}
I.e. you have not transitioned any new physics, just a coordinate transformation of the known spacetime.

In fact it is quite useful to consider different times. E.g. you may consider the so-called conformal time for which,
\begin{equation}
ds^2=a^2(\eta) (d\eta^2-d\vec{x}^2) 
\end{equation}
You may notice that it is proportional to the Minkowski metric. So the lightcones $ds^2=0$ are the same in this coordinates as in the Minkowski spacetime. This make it very easy to study the causal structure of the spacetime in such coordinates.

Comment: But wouldn't this b(t) cause the time period of a lightwave to increase or decrease with time? Is this still the same as the physics of the regular metric?

Comment: When you let space expand you define comoving distance and physical distance, and relate them by a scale factor that changes with time. What if we treat time the same, and define comoving time as the time between two standard events, and let this expand. Will this lead to any measurable consequences?